# How to check unique while update on django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have successfully check validation of unique while user is registered, 
but during his profile update, how do I check the unique email during the update?

**views.py**

```
def UpdateProfile(request, user_id):
    data = UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = profileForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('dd')
    else:
        form = profileForm(instance=data)    
    context = {
        'data' : data,
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile_update.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class profileForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id' : "firstName" ,
                    'placeholder' : 'Enter Name', 'autofocus' : 'autofocus', 'value' : 12 }),validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(5), validators.MaxLengthValidator(10)])
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id' : "inputEmail" ,
                    'placeholder' : 'Enter Email'}),validators=[validators.validate_email])

    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id' : "username" ,
                    'placeholder' : 'Enter Username'}),validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(5), validators.MaxLengthValidator(8)])

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id' : "inputPassword" ,
                     'placeholder' : 'Enter Password'}),validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(5), validators.MaxLengthValidator(8)])

    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), required=False)    

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        user_id = cleaned_data.get('user_id')
        print(user_id)
        uname = cleaned_data.get('username')
        print(UserModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email))
        if UserModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email) == True and UserModel.objects.filter(username__iexact=uname) == True:            
            # self._errors['email'] 
            raise forms.ValidationError({'email': ["Email is already exist",], 'username': ["Username is already exist",]})

        if UserModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email) == True:            
            # self._errors['email'] 
            raise forms.ValidationError({'email': ["Email is already exist",]})

        # if UserModel.objects.filter(username__iexact=uname).exists() == True:            
        if UserModel.objects.filter(username__iexact=uname) == True:            
            # self._errors['email'] 
            raise forms.ValidationError({'username': ["Username is already exist",]})

        return self.cleaned_data     
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = '__all__'

        labels = {
            "username": "uname"
        }
```

Comment: Where is your model, or the view that's handling this? How can we help fix code that we can't see? What is your DB configuration for email addresses?

Comment: could you put some code please ?

Comment: If you add the unique constraint to the field and use `ModelForm`s correctly you will not have to worry about validating uniqueness as the `ModelForm` will handle it for you

Comment: i  have added code now tell me

Comment: @lain but its not give me a proper validation error,

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"? If the field has a unique constraint (`unique=True`) then you can get rid of your clean method as uniqueness checking is done by ModelForms anyway

Comment: @lain its work for sign up , i want when user do update profile

Comment: That's the form I'm talking about, remove the clean method

Comment: @lain, seriously i do all the things from my side, but found nothing, infact as you said remove clean after do i got no message on my form having duplicate entry

Comment: Does UserModel have unique=True on the username/email field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198760/discussion-between-krishna-and-iain-shelvington).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check  unique email like this  while updating the user

```
  def clean_email (self):
      email  = self.cleaned_data ['email']
      email_exists = User.objects.filter (email=email).exclude (pk=self.instance.pk) # excluding the current user from queryset
      if self.instance and self.instance.pk and not email_exists:
          return email 
      else :
          raise ValidationError ("email already exists")
```

Comment: Thanks its works like a charm.

I need one more help. Do you please help me

Comment: i tried to upload image using django
but not be able to upload,
I added media_root, media_url in settings.py, and urls.py i wrote +static code,
and in view request.FILES

Comment: I think You better ask a new question for this